# How can I create circular shape with multiple objects and animate them?

Tags: animation, modifiers

Please refer the video below:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_H-Tk5pY9-8

I am trying to re-create the first 2 seconds opening sequence where multiple cards placed side-by-side and creating opening in the middle where objects move and let the hole getting enlarged.

I have tried arrays using empty in the center of scene and created copies, however it doesn't create the same form.

Is there a way to make it similar to the reference video, and apply the animation?

Thanks in advance for your valued time.

Comment: While files, images, and external videos may be helpful additions to questions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on viewing a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be searched for and indexed thus helping future users with similar issues find it.

Comment: if you are satisfied with this https://youtu.be/xR_z8_Zg6XA then i write a tutorial for this

Comment: Hello Chris,
I have watched the video and yes, please write a tutorial for me. It will be much appreciated!

Comment: please be patient, but i think tomorrow i can make it.

Comment: @zouzouni: tutorial link is in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. model the card e.g. like this

[image]

2. move the card in edit mode on your x-axis
3. Duplicate card with CTRL-D, rotate on z-Axis 60 degrees
4. repeat step 4 with CTRL-R 4 times so you have 6 cards in total
5. Make a 2nd card, and move it in edit mode on your x-Axis too
6. Rotate that card 30 degrees on z-Axis
7. Repeat steps 3-4 for that second card so get something like this:

[image]

8. add an empty as controller for the x-rotation of the cards
9. add an object constraint like this to every card:

[image]

10. animate the x rotation about 60 degrees for this controller
11. add a new master controller
12. parent all cards to that master controller
13. animate the z rotation about 30 degrees for this controller
14. add a short x-rotation for the controller from 8)

result:

[image]

video tutorial:  https://youtu.be/RXuNw4u3z1M

Comment: Thank you very much Chris. You're a saver!

Comment: You are welcome! Glad I could help!

Comment: For some reason, now I want to eat a chocolate.